# Why can't Max be used as a function in this case?

Tags: c++

I just started C++ and I don't understand why `Max` cannot be used as a function in this case.
What I'm trying to do in this code is find the maximum number between the first one and the forth one, on any random number that only has 4 digits.
I've tried inserting `Max` to `int`, also to `cin` but it still does not work. any ideas on how to do it?
Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    int Max, a, b, c, d;

    cin>>Max>>a>>b>>c>>d;

    Max(a,b) = (a+b+abs(a-b))/2;

    Max(b,c) = (b+c+abs(b-c))/2;

    Max(c,d) = (c+d+abs(c-d))/2;

    Max = (Max(a,b)+Max(b,c)+Max(c,d)+abs(Max(a,b)-Max(b,c)-Max(c,d)))/2;





}
```

Comment: Where do you define a `Max` function?

Comment: `Max(a,b) = ` where did you pick this syntax up from?

Comment: Simply use `std::max` from `<algorithm>`

Comment: You need to define a function Max that returns an integer `int Max(int a, int b){}`. Also, as pointed out by @Gereon there is a standard library function for this. But I will assume you are not really trying to re-invent the wheel but instead are trying to learn C++ and this is just an example you picked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @UnholySheep the syntax Max comes from Maximum because I want to find the maximum numbers between first and last.

Comment: Your question seems a bit off. Perhaps you could explain why you think `Max` can be used as a function when you declared it to be an integer?

Comment: You are confusing the compiler.  You have an `int` variable named `Max`; not a function.  Search your favorite reference for function declaration syntax.

Comment: @JaMiT `Max` means Maximum so i thought it was going to work if I declare it as an integer. However when I remove it from `int`  it tells me `Max` "was not declared in this scope"

Comment: @jaketherazvy That tells me nothing new. I asked *why* you thought it was going to work.

Comment: Learning C++ by trying to guess the syntax is going to be tricky.

Comment: 1: There is not function called `Max()`. 2: inside the function `main()` you have a variable called `Max` so the compiler will always use the variable inside `main()`. The scope rules of C++ says use the first valid version of `Max` you find. If your syntax for that use is illegal generate a compiler error. Now if you use the function `std::max()` then it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion, you'll need to study function syntaxes.

A variable declaration:
`int Max;`
The above declares a *variable* called `Max`.

A function declaration:
`int Max(int a, int b);`
The above *declares* a function, `Max`, which takes 2 `int` parameters: `a` and `b`.

A function definition could be:

```
int Max(int a, int b)
{
  if (a > b)
  {
    return a;
  }
  return b;
}
```

For extra points, find the calculus formula for return the maximum value of 2 integers. :-)

**Notes:**
1. The above function can't be on the Left-Hand Side (LHS) of an assignment operation (it doesn't make sense, how would the function be assigned a value?).
2. The function returns a value.  You should assign the value to a variable or print it:

```
   int maximum = Max(3,15);
   std::cout << "Maximum of 4, 24 is: " << Max(24,4) << "\n";
```